# Multiple async methods, one completion handler

Tags: ios, completion

I have two async methods:

```
- (void)login: (void (^)(BOOL))completion{
    // some network stuff with completion
}
```

and

```
- (void)download: (void (^)(BOOL))completion{
        // some network stuff with completion
    }
```

For a background fetch, I need both methods to be completed, and return just one completion.

I could of course, nest the methods, as such

```
 - (void)login: (void (^)(BOOL))completion{
      //....
       [self download:^(BOOL success) {
           //....
                 if (success){
                     completion(true);
                  }
         }];
    }
```

However, as soon as I add one or more methods that need to be completed at the same time, code gets messy.

I remember having read about a way, with which you could just kind of group all those methods on one thread, but I just don't seem to have the right vocabulary to find that here on SO or elsewhere.

I hope you understand what I'm talking about, and point me in the right direction.

thanks ahead

Comment: Are you thinking of dispatch_barrier_async?

Comment: Look into dispatch groups. You might find these links useful: [1](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/) [2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/63338/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-2)

Comment: I would love to. You pointed me to the right direction, but your answer doesn't contain that direction. For me, what worked was:

dispatch_group_t serviceGroup = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(serviceGroup);

[asyncMethod:^(BOOL Success) {
                if (Success){
                    dispatch_group_leave(serviceGroup);
                }
            }];

Answer (score 2):

If the task really presents a dependency and it's possible that you have to add more methods in the future maybe you should consider use [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is pass the `completion block` down to the `download` method so when download completes the completion is chained all the way back up the caller like so:

```
- (void)login: (void (^)(BOOL))completion{
    // some network stuff with completion
    [self download:completion];
}

- (void)download: (void (^)(BOOL))completion{
    completion(YES);
    // some network stuff with completion
}
```